# Data insert into SQLITE with Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I'm trying to create a function to insert into SQLITE.
I keep getting error : -

Error:(62, 23) error: cannot find symbol variable action_settings
Error:(50, 36) error: cannot find symbol variable menu

I checked the code doesn't seem to understand where about went wrong. I'm totally new to Java and Android Programming.

Below are the source codes:-

DatabaseHelper.java

```
package com.example.adrian.insert;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

/**
 * Created by ProgrammingKnowledge on 4/3/2015.
 */
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Student.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "student_table";
    public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
    public static final String COL_2 = "NAME";
    public static final String COL_3 = "SURNAME";
    public static final String COL_4 = "MARKS";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME +" (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,NAME TEXT,SURNAME TEXT,MARKS INTEGER)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean insertData(String name,String surname,String marks) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_2,name);
        contentValues.put(COL_3,surname);
        contentValues.put(COL_4,marks);
        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null ,contentValues);
        if(result == -1)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
}
```

MainActivity.Java

```
package com.example.adrian.insert;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    DatabaseHelper myDb;
    EditText editName,editSurname,editMarks;
    Button btnAddData;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        editName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_name);
        editSurname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_surname);
        editMarks = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_Marks);
        btnAddData = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_add);
        AddData();
    }

    public  void AddData() {
        btnAddData.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        boolean isInserted = myDb.insertData(editName.getText().toString(),
                                editSurname.getText().toString(),
                                editMarks.getText().toString() );
                        if(isInserted =true)
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Data Inserted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        else
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Data not Inserted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
        );
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Name"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Surname"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText_name"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Marks"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText_surname"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText_name"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText_surname"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView2" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText_Marks"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText_surname"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView3" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add Data"
        android:id="@+id/button_add"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText_Marks"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="76dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thank you for your help.

Adrian.

Comment: Its looking for a menu item with the ID of action_settings, which doesn't exist.

Answer (score -1):

remove this if block

```
if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
    return true;
}
```